# Kettle : 'Get a file with FTP' is not fetching any files from FTP server

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am using 'Get a file with FTP' in kettle job. I am using active FTP connection and full name of the file as Wildcard(regular expression ) and a remote directory.

I simulated the FTP server locally using File Zilla and it does picks up the file but it's not picking up from actual FTP server.

Note: I am able to fetch the file by using FTP get command on command prompt.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: in some case Get a file from FTP does not work. try to use Get a file from SFTP and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: SFTP is not allowed by the server. 
I am using VPN to connect to the network where FTP server is located. As VPN is being used, server supports only FTP. It doesn't support SFTP,FTPS.

Comment: have you tried what i suggested ?

Comment: Yes I did, test connection only fails. It is specified that the server allows only ftp.

Comment: FTP server had some issue. FTP get is working as expected now. Thank you.